# Trigger a click in a child class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to find ways to trigger the dropdown (of class `"update-message-button"`) using jquery when I click in the blank spaces of the parent `<td>` (of class `"message-row"`) and even when clicked on its corresponding `<td>` (class `"message-type-row"`).
I have attached my jquery code, but the dropdown doesn't get triggered.

Thanks in advance

```js
$(".message-row").on("click", function () {
    $(".update-message-button").trigger("click");
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
     <td class="message-row" scope="row">
       <div class="dropdown dropleft">
         <a class="update-message-button" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             {{this.message}}
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item update-message-id" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="{{this._id}}">Update</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Remove</a>
         </div>
       </div>
    </td>
    <td class="message-type-row">
        {{this.messageType}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. So what exactly does “not working” mean? Do you get errors? // Assuming you have multiple of these rows, you might want to start by selecting the `.update-message-button` that is actually inside of the current `.message-row` you clicked on, right now, you are just selecting the _first_ element with that class in the whole document.

Comment: If I put a console.log("some string") in the function, I can see "some string" getting printed recursively in the console.

Comment: This is the error i got running your code: "InternalError: too much recursion"...

Comment: why are you using jquery ?

Comment: @celyes yess, same here

Comment: @TilakMaddy what is the other option?

Comment: Vanilla JavaScript is sooo enough for this haha

Comment: you can use ES6 and you'll be just fine

Answer (score 0):

Your script works,

BUT since `.update-message-button` is within `.message-row`

a click within `.message-row` triggers your `trigger` which in turn triggers the parent `on('click')`, and enters into an endless loop.

You might have to rethink your design, or use maybe: `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the execution after the first `click`.

#### Edit:

This works:

```
$(document).on("click", ".message-row",function () {
   $(".update-message-button").triggerHandler("click");
});
```

https://codepen.io/ron7/pen/VweGVyb

Comment: Check my Edit and try that

Answer (score 0):

It says you're new...so welcome to Stack!

- If you don't use a JavaScript Framework at your workplace...jQuery is a perfectly fine approach

In looking at your HTML & explanation...it isn't really "that clear" what you are trying to accomplish.  And, if I am correct, I feel your approach has some issues.  That said...I will "try" to stay within the boundaries of what I believe you are asking (and try not to change it too much).

It "looks" like you want to...

- Display a "dropdown" (of sorts) when the parent is 'clicked'
- Manage the "update & remove" options when chosen

In anayzing the HTML you provide...you may also be wanting to notify other components of the users choice (so I added that too).

SIDE NOTES:

- I "compressed" the CSS & HTML down a bit for you
- Message...is your 'Record Class'
- MessagePublisher...is your 'HTML Template Class'
- SubscriptionController...is the 'Subscriber Class' (this is optional)
- logger...logs to the console (handy...but also optional)

Cheers!

```js
    var logger = (function () {
        return {
            log: function () {
                if (console) {
                    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                    console.log.apply(console, args);
                }
            }
        }
    })();

    function Message(id, messageType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.messageType = messageType;
    }

    function MessagePublisher(record) {

        var _record = record,
            _$message = null,
            _$messageOptions = null,
            _$messageType = null,
            _$dropdown = null,
            _$updater,
            _$destroyer;

        return {
            dataBind: function (ele) {

                // Elements
                _$message = $(ele);
                _$messageOptions = $('.message-options', _$message);
                _$messageType = $('.message-type', _$message);
                _$dropdown = $('.dropdown', _$messageOptions);
                _$updater = $('.update-message', _$dropdown);
                _$destroyer = $('.destroy-message', _$dropdown);

                // Values
                _$messageType.text(_record.messageType);
                _$updater.attr('data-id', _record.id)
                _$destroyer.attr('data-id', _record.id)

                // Events
                _$messageOptions.on('click', this.on.click.messageOptions);
                _$destroyer.on('click', { publisher: this }, this.on.click.removeMessage);
                _$updater.on('click', { publisher: this }, this.on.click.updateMessage);
            },
            on: {
                click: {
                    messageOptions: function (e) {

                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (!_$dropdown.is(':visible')) {
                            _$dropdown.show();
                        }
                    },
                    removeMessage: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(e.data.publisher).trigger('destroy::record', [_record])
                    },
                    updateMessage: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(e.data.publisher).trigger('update::record', [_record])
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    function SubscriptionController() {
        return {
            on: {
                destroy: function (e, record) {

                    logger.log('DESTROY', [record]);
                },
                update: function (e, record) {

                    logger.log('UPDATE', [record]);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Subscriber
        window.subscriber = new SubscriptionController();

        // Publishers
        var $messages = $('.message');
        $.each($messages, function (index, ele) {

            var id = index+1;
            var record = new Message(id, 'Awesome Message Type');
            var controller = new MessagePublisher(record);

            controller.dataBind(ele);

            // Apply Subscriptions
            $(controller).on('destroy::record', window.subscriber.on.destroy);
            $(controller).on('update::record', window.subscriber.on.update);
        });
    });
```

```css
table { width: 600px; }
table tbody tr.message { }
table tbody tr.message td { border: 1px solid #e3e2e1; padding: 5px; }
table tbody tr.message td { width: 50%; }

.message { }
.message .message-options { cursor: pointer; }
.message .message-options .dropdown { display: none; }
.message .message-options .dropdown a { display: block; }
.message .message-options .dropdown .sub-menu { }
.message .message-options .dropdown .sub-menu .menu-item { cursor: pointer; }

.message .message-type { }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="message">
            <td valign="top" class="message-options">

                <div class="dropdown">

                    <a class="dropdown-message">Please Choose an Option</a>

                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item update-message">Update</a>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item destroy-message">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </td>
            <td valign="top" class="message-type">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```